# Cutting a dendrogram in R

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend

I am trying to cut this dendrogram into 3 groups: (T24, T1, T17, etc.), (T12, T15, T6, etc.) and (T2, T8, T3, T9)

[image]

I have tried using cutree(hc, k=3, h=400) , but it continues to make the same groups.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code.

```
#temps must have date/time as column headers, not row headers
load(temps)
distMatrix <- dist(temps)
#create label colors
labelColors = c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3", "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33")
# cut dendrogram in 3 clusters
clusMember = cutree(hc, k=3, h=400)
colLab <- function(n) {
  if (is.leaf(n)) {
  a <- attributes(n)
  labCol <- labelColors[clusMember[which(names(clusMember) == a$label)]]
  attr(n, "nodePar") <- c(a$nodePar, lab.col = labCol)
  }
  n
}
hcd = as.dendrogram(hc)
clusDendro = dendrapply(hcd, colLab)
plot(clusDendro, main = "Cluster Analysis")
```

Comment: You can*t, because there is not height (y axis) that represents those three groups.

Comment: You can just do a smaller height, and combine groups yourself afterwards.  The docs for cuttree say if you specify `k` it overrides `h` if both are given.

Answer (score 4):

You example is not reproducible in the sense that we don't have access to the data.
What I can say is that you should look at the [dendextend R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/). It offers functions for cutting a dendrogram, as well as coloring labels and branches. The [Quick Introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/Quick_Introduction.html) manual shows the basic use of functions such as `labels_colors` and `color_branches` for producing plots such as this:

[image]

In your case, since your branches seem to be in the same height, you are not likely to have direct control over their cuts. What you could do is use the `branches_attr_by_clusters` to specifically control the the colors of the sub-clusters you care for. Here is an example:

```
x <- c(1:3, 6:8)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x), method = "ave"))
library(dendextend)
labels(dend) <- x[order.dendrogram(dend)]

# due to the ties - there is specific reason to have this be these 3 clusters:
cutree(dend, k = 3)[order.dendrogram(dend)]

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
dend1 <- color_branches(dend, k = 3)
dend1 <- color_labels(dend1, k = 3)
plot(dend1, main = "default cuts by cutree")
# let's force it to be another 3 clusters:
dend2 <- branches_attr_by_clusters(dend, c(1, 2,2, 3,3,3), c("gold", "darkgreen", "blue"))
# coloring the labels is actually the easiest part:
labels_colors(dend2) <- c("gold", "darkgreen", "blue")[c(1, 2,2, 3,3,3)]
plot(dend2, main = "Manual cuts")
```

[image]

Comment: how to use color_branches after this to add for heatmap.2 `ColSideColors`?

Comment: Nevermind it would be `labels_colors(dend2)[order(order.dendrogram(dend2))]`

Comment: I think the labels need to be unique here also in `labels(dend)`

Comment: Confirmed unique or doesn't have to be unique but with the correct order of the manual breaks.